# Extract information from response ID Angular

Tags: angularjs, post, fetch

I am using POST to send a JSON raw body and in response I am getting an ID. But I need to show specific information passed with the JSON to that particular ID that has been created in my view.

I am new in Angularjs . ***My controller part :-***

```
$scope.master = {};

     $scope.addSegment = function(fn) {
    $scope.master = angular.copy(fn);
         $http.post("url", $scope.master).then(function(data) { 
                $scope.Info = data;
                $scope.infoName = data.Name;
                $scope.infoRoll = data.Roll;
                $scope.infoDuration = data.Duration;
                growl.success("Created");
                console.log($scope.Info + $scope.infoName + $scope.infoRoll + $scope.infoDuration);           
                  },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                       growl.error("Something went wrong");
                  });
                };
```

I am passing three components from user input to here `$scope.master = {};` and an ID is been created successfully which I can see in response. But not the names , roll and duration. How to get these infos and show in views each time when new ID is created.

**EDIT:-HTML**

```
<label for="reg_select_multiple"><b>Children</b></label>
     <select multiple="multiple" id="reg_select_multiple" class="form-control">
         <option ng-repeat="">{{Info}}</option>

      </select>
```

Comment: Can you provide to us what content your data console.log(data)

Comment: @SiderTopalov just a new ID for each POST. a number ex: 10 , then new POST another ID 11.

Comment: If your data is something like that data = {id: 1}; then you can't do this data.Name, data.Roll, data.Duration just because they are not existing in your response. You should modified your response to return you not only id but and these Name,Roll,Duration and after that you will be able to access them in front-end. Or you can pass them from your view to controller and use them after successful post

Comment: @SiderTopalov my input JSON body is `{ "Name": " " , "Roll": " " , "Duration": " " }` to that response I get is ID number that's it. But now what I want to do is to show Name , Roll , Duration in my view for each ID in a list.

Comment: Provide your view please

Comment: @SiderTopalov Updated my post please see.

Comment: You are view is wrong i will leave you an answer give me a second

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="reg_select_multiple"><b>Children</b></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="reg_select_multiple" class="form-control">
   <option>{{infoName}}</option>
   <option>{{infoRoll}}</option>
   <option>{{infoDuration}}</option>
</select>
```

also read about how to use ng-repeat from [angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: I know this , but the problem is  there is no data coming in infoName infoRoll infoDuration. When I did in only Info then ID is displaying.

Comment: Just console.log(data) for us if there is no data or keys are empty("") then problem comes from your backend

Comment: `{data: 224, status: 201, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "Created"}` This is what I am getting when doing `console.log(data)`. As u can see `224` which is the ID i am getting. I want to extract Name, Roll , Duration from it to show in my view.

Comment: As you can see there is no what you want, if i not wrong data: 224, is your ID, that mean the problem comes from your back-end

Comment: Any way around to extract the body info which I am passing  with particular id ?